# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: .net, winforms, exception

I'm working in a Windows project (done a long time back by Visual Studio 2003 by .NET 1.03**). When I try to run some forms I am getting a strange error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

The inner exception is this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. --> Value was either too large or too small for a UInt16.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at Sabre.SabreRTS.UI.Forms.OrganizationService.OrganizationService.GetWorkCentre() in F:\tEndDEVNEW\UI\Forms\Web References\OrganizationService\Reference.cs:line 928
at Sabre.SabreRTS.UI.Forms.ShiftException.PopulateWorkCentrecombo() in f:\****\ui\forms\shiftexception.cs:line 933
at Sabre.SabreRTS.UI.Forms.ShiftException..ctor() in f:\****\ui\forms\shiftexception.cs:line 148
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

This has happened mostly when the variable is initiated (this code was sent to production many many times without this issue).

Is there solution for this?

(Is this caused by corruption of the framework itself?. Further, my PC have all the frameworks up to latest version.)

Comment: Your program is using a web service to contact a server that appears to be owned by Sabre.  Sounds like a reservation system.  The web service is falling over on what appears to be an overflow of a 16-bit integer.  This doesn't have anything to do with .NET.  Contact the service owner for support.

Comment: @Hans: Do they, perchance, make printers? I hear they have a habit of catching fire.

Comment: Thank you Hans, there was a issue with service .